# Displaying products per store in a marketplace

Tags: commerce

Don't know if I am skipping an obvious available feature but I am not seeing it.

I am building a marketplace, I have been struggling to display products of particular stores, visiting stores doesn't show the products of the store so I have been trying to make a view of the products belonging to a store. I want on the store page, products belonging to the store will be listed under the store profile. I am using `commerce_marketplace`. I have not been able to get the right contextual filters to display the products of a store on the store profile. What I am building is a showcase of stores, you click a store and find products of the store.

For store owners and admins, `commerce_marketplace` does a great job: on store profiles, there is a 'Product's tab. But for anonymous users and customers, no 'Products per Store' displays.

Is it me missing an obvious way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of trying all kinds of Views setting, I finally found a solution to this issue, https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3153177